Finding current Rust cdylib file from inside the `#[test]` code
In order to test my Rust cdylib crate, I need to load it into a 3rd party C++ app. This means cargo test must compile my crate into some .so file like target/debug/libmycrate.so
Ergonomically, it is best for me to simply add some magic test_my_lib!() to my src/lib.rs -- which would add #[test] function to do the needed steps.
cargo test does not seem to create an  .so file, only cargo build does. Is there a way to force cargo test into generating it? Or is there another way to generate that lib somewhere inside target/debug/deps/...?

Even if you could make cargo test emit .so, it still won't work because you cannot make it load your C++.

why not?  My #[test] fn my_test(), when it runs, can start a new process, and tell that process to use the .so file.

Well then you don't need it to emit .so for the tested code but for some other thing, you can do that with a build script.

how can a build script build something that later references itself???  If the lib is being built as cdylib, and it also contains unit tests, and some runner (?) executes those unit tests - the tests need a way to find the name of the cdylib of itself. If on the other hand tests are created as a bin, then i just need to instruct builder to produce both targets - not sure how.

Have a separate package for the unit tests, not dependent of your main package (it can't reference it anyway). In that package have a build script that builds your main package.

I think you should be able to use some combination of custom test harness and/or build script to achieve what you want.
